# Terminal window spews out some logs on every startup after a hack-installation of Vagrant on M1 silicon

Tags: macos, conda, zsh, vmware-fusion, rosetta

I don't remember when exactly the behaviour started, but I suspect it was after following the [instructions](https://gist.github.com/sbailliez/f22db6434ac84eccb6d3c8833c85ad92) for installing the Vagrant/VMWareFusion Virtual Machines for the purpose of running Vagrant on an M1 machine. Particularly, I think the Rosetta installation step broke something with the Conda environment, or it could have been the VMWare_Fusion, I am not really sure even to where to look for the leads...

On every startup of a new terminal window it spews out this (which is not a problem, but is annoying and I want to know the reason behind it).

```
Last login: Fri Feb  3 10:20:58 on ttys013
CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV=base
CONDA_EXE=/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/conda
CONDA_PREFIX=/Users/administrateur/miniconda3
CONDA_PROMPT_MODIFIER='(base) '
CONDA_PYTHON_EXE=/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/python
CONDA_SHLVL=1
CONDA_SUBDIR=osx-64
HOME=/Users/administrateur
HOMEBREW_CELLAR=/opt/homebrew/Cellar
HOMEBREW_PREFIX=/opt/homebrew
HOMEBREW_REPOSITORY=/opt/homebrew
INFOPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/info:
LC_CTYPE=UTF-8
LOGNAME=administrateur
LaunchInstanceID=<...>
MANPATH=/opt/homebrew/share/man::
MallocSpaceEfficient=1
OLDPWD=/Users/administrateur
PATH='/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin:/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/condabin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Applications/VMware Fusion Tech Preview.app/Contents/Public:/Library/Apple/usr/bin'
PWD=/Users/administrateur
SHELL=/bin/zsh
SHLVL=1
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.m4msYyw1Un/Listeners
TERM=xterm-256color
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=447
TERM_SESSION_ID=<...>
TMPDIR=/var/folders/lb/nwlpglqd33d3539m3f8wntyr0000gn/T/
USER=administrateur
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
_CE_CONDA=''
_CE_M=''
__CFBundleIdentifier=com.apple.Terminal
(base) administrateur@machine ~ %
```

UPD:
The contents of `~./zshrc`

```
alias ll="ls -l"
alias lt='ls -lt | head'
alias lS='ls -lS'

# >>> conda initialize >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$('/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
    else
        export PATH="/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda initialize <<<
```

The `conda.csh` file looks like this

```
setenv CONDA_EXE "/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/conda"
setenv _CONDA_ROOT "/Users/administrateur/miniconda3"
setenv _CONDA_EXE "/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/conda"
setenv CONDA_PYTHON_EXE "/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/python"
# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause

if (! $?_CONDA_EXE) then
  set _CONDA_EXE="${PWD}/conda/shell/bin/conda"
else
  if ("$_CONDA_EXE" == "") then
      set _CONDA_EXE="${PWD}/conda/shell/bin/conda"
  endif
endif

if ("`alias conda`" == "") then
    if ($?_CONDA_EXE) then
        # _CONDA_PFX is named so as not to cause confusion with CONDA_PREFIX
        # If nested backticks were possible we wouldn't use any variables here.
        set _CONDA_PFX=`dirname "${_CONDA_EXE}"`
        set _CONDA_PFX=`dirname "${_CONDA_PFX}"`
        alias conda source "${_CONDA_PFX}/etc/profile.d/conda.csh"
        # And for good measure, get rid of it afterwards.
        unset _CONDA_PFX
    else
        alias conda source "${PWD}/conda/shell/etc/profile.d/conda.csh"
    endif
    setenv CONDA_SHLVL 0
    if (! $?prompt) then
        set prompt=""
    endif
else
    switch ( "${1}" )
        case "activate":
            set ask_conda="`(setenv prompt '${prompt}' ; '${_CONDA_EXE}' shell.csh activate '${2}' ${argv[3-]})`"
            set conda_tmp_status=$status
            if( $conda_tmp_status != 0 ) exit ${conda_tmp_status}
            eval "${ask_conda}"
            rehash
            breaksw
        case "deactivate":
            set ask_conda="`(setenv prompt '${prompt}' ; '${_CONDA_EXE}' shell.csh deactivate '${2}' ${argv[3-]})`"
            set conda_tmp_status=$status
            if( $conda_tmp_status != 0 ) exit ${conda_tmp_status}
            eval "${ask_conda}"
            rehash
            breaksw
        case "install" | "update" | "upgrade" | "remove" | "uninstall":
            $_CONDA_EXE $argv[1-]
            set ask_conda="`(setenv prompt '${prompt}' ; '${_CONDA_EXE}' shell.csh reactivate)`"
            set conda_tmp_status=$status
            if( $conda_tmp_status != 0 ) exit ${conda_tmp_status}
            eval "${ask_conda}"
            rehash
            breaksw
        default:
            $_CONDA_EXE $argv[1-]
            breaksw
    endsw
endif
```

The contents of `conda.sh`:

```
export CONDA_EXE='/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/conda'
export _CE_M=''
export _CE_CONDA=''
export CONDA_PYTHON_EXE='/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/python'

# Copyright (C) 2012 Anaconda, Inc
# SPDX-License-Identifier: BSD-3-Clause

__conda_exe() (
    "$CONDA_EXE" $_CE_M $_CE_CONDA "$@"
)

__conda_hashr() {
    if [ -n "${ZSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        \rehash
    elif [ -n "${POSH_VERSION:+x}" ]; then
        :  # pass
    else
        \hash -r
    fi
}

__conda_activate() {
    if [ -n "${CONDA_PS1_BACKUP:+x}" ]; then
        # Handle transition from shell activated with conda <= 4.3 to a subsequent activation
        # after conda updated to >= 4.4. See issue #6173.
        PS1="$CONDA_PS1_BACKUP"
        \unset CONDA_PS1_BACKUP
    fi
    \local ask_conda
    ask_conda="$(PS1="${PS1:-}" __conda_exe shell.posix "$@")" || \return
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __conda_hashr
}

__conda_reactivate() {
    \local ask_conda
    ask_conda="$(PS1="${PS1:-}" __conda_exe shell.posix reactivate)" || \return
    \eval "$ask_conda"
    __conda_hashr
}

conda() {
    \local cmd="${1-__missing__}"
    case "$cmd" in
        activate|deactivate)
            __conda_activate "$@"
            ;;
        install|update|upgrade|remove|uninstall)
            __conda_exe "$@" || \return
            __conda_reactivate
            ;;
        *)
            __conda_exe "$@"
            ;;
    esac
}

if [ -z "${CONDA_SHLVL+x}" ]; then
    \export CONDA_SHLVL=0
    # In dev-mode CONDA_EXE is python.exe and on Windows
    # it is in a different relative location to condabin.
    if [ -n "${_CE_CONDA:+x}" ] && [ -n "${WINDIR+x}" ]; then
        PATH="$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
    else
        PATH="$(\dirname "$(\dirname "$CONDA_EXE")")/condabin${PATH:+":${PATH}"}"
    fi
    \export PATH

    # We're not allowing PS1 to be unbound. It must at least be set.
    # However, we're not exporting it, which can cause problems when starting a second shell
    # via a first shell (i.e. starting zsh from bash).
    if [ -z "${PS1+x}" ]; then
        PS1=
    fi
fi
```

Comment: Try `env` on the command line. Does the output look similar to this?

Comment: Yes, it does. It outputs even slightly more of the same gibberish

Comment: Check your `~/.zshrc` file. Looks like there's a loose `/usr/bin/env` run somewhere after the **conda initialize** section. If nothing obvious, then try commenting out sections and starting new shells to see what stops it.

Comment: thank you, @merv, in the `~/.zshrc` there is indeed a conda activation variable that is responsible for the spewage when being `eval`uated, which is `__conda_setup="$('/Users/administrateur/miniconda3/bin/conda' 'shell.zsh' 'hook' 2> /dev/null)"` 

I am searching now for the conda description file where the conda's variables are defined in order to intercept the line that is causing the problems...

 `/usr/bin/env` is a binary file, how can I inspect/modify it?

Comment: That line should not emit anything. In fact it is not expected that anything in the “conda initialize” section should be edited. Perhaps you can share the file contents?

Comment: @merv thanks for staying with me :) I updated the post with the contents of `.zshrc`, `conda.csh` and `conda.sh` files